# Population sampling for geospatial machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, geospatial

I'm trying to build a predictive model of geospatial features based on distance from other features in a mixed urban suburban environment eg the likelihood of an office block being at a location based on the distances to the nearest road, housing estate, and shopping area. I have a set of feature locations, but the blocks are not scattered uniformly across the area in some areas they are very sparse and others very dense. Using decision trees to predict the presence or not of a school at a location I need a training set, of both positive and negative cases. How should I create a sample of such cases?

Answer (score 1):

You would need data of the following format:

`nearestRoad`, `housingEstate`, `shoppingDistrict`, ... , `schoolPresent`

`nearestRoad` would be a `realNumber`, `housingEstate` and `shoppingDistrict` would be binary variables (I'm guessing). Have you check out google maps? Do they provide you with an API that lets you query particular (lat,long) coordinates? If they did, then you could generate the dataset as follows:

Suppose a school exists at coordinates `(x,y)`. Then do a `gridsearch` with a radius of say 5 miles to get the precise value of each feature. So, for instance, maybe you find a shopping district at coordinates `(x+1, y+2)`, so that feature would equal 1 for this particular instance.

This may be tedious but if such an API exists, it definitely seems possible.